# JavaScript - Cannot access the clipboard with ctl + c and crt + v

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard

I tried to access the clipboard but Chrome and Firefox only interpret `undefined`. How can I improve the code?

JavaScript:

```
function handlePaste(e) {
for (var i = 0 ; i < e.clipboardData.items.length ; i++) {
var item = e.clipboardData.items[i];
console.log(item );
```

[source of that code](http://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2013/09/25/upload-image-by-copy-and-paste/)

Comment: This seems like it's not a standard API yet.  Each browser has its own way of doing it.  It works fine in Chrome 34 and Firefox 24 if you do it the way the browser wants: http://jsfiddle.net/42jLC/

Comment: That can be a hassle to implement, I'd look at this it's very helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: I think at this point your best bet is to use flash, but remember that won't work on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there is no easy way, since browsers disable this kind of behaviour. Even google docs asks you to use your keyboard shortcuts to copy and paste.

There is a library that uses flash to achive what you want, but again, not 100% reliable.

http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/

Comment: keyboard shortcuts to copy and paste, that is what I would like to have, is google using flash?

Comment: @daisy i meant that even google docs cant access your clipboard. They tell you to copy and paste text using your keyboard.